# What does a quality management plan look like?

Tags: planning, quality, quality-management

I'm developing a quality management plan as part of a study assignment.

I guess I'm a bit lost on where to begin.

What general structure should a quality management document have? Or will it look different for each project?

Should this document list specific measures to be taken in order to increase quality (e.g. testing all software components, acceptance criteria on all user stories, incorporating customer feedback, etc)?

Should I be incorporating quality tools: SIPOC, CTQ, pilots, lessons learned, etc.?

How do I decide which tools should be used? Based on the particular quality needs of the project?

Answer (score 1):

```
What general structure should a quality management document have? Or will it look different for each project?
```

Structure is always important when it comes to documentation & planning. That said each project will have different requirements. Don't force each project to look the same.

```
Should this document list specific measures to be taken in order to increase quality.
```

Yes.

```
Should I be incorporating quality tools
```

Tools, yes. Lessons learned no.

```
How do I decide which tools should be used? Based on the particular quality needs of the project?
```

Again, each project is different. What works for one project doesn't always work for others.

I myself have never worked within a corporation that generates quality management plans for projects, rather we've incorporated such plans directly into our development & business processes. However, if I was to generate such a plan I would create a document that looks something like this:

1. Quality Management Approach
2. Quality Management Objectives
3. Project Quality Control
4. Team Roles & Responsibilities
5. Quality Tools

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note, in addition to what Jesse said, Management Plans are living documents.  There are things that should be addressed but if something isn't working, change it.

Things I have in the current Management Plans worth noting:

Configuration Management (Even just a snippet if there is a larger stand alone document)
Risk Management (Same as above)
Test Approach (Unit Testing, Iterative Testing, Alpha, Beta, descriptions of testing phases)
Methodology (Scrum, XP, Waterfall, Kanban, anything)

> Should this document list specific measures to be taken in order to
>   increase quality (e.g. testing all software components, acceptance
>   criteria on all user stories, incorporating customer feedback, etc)?

All of your examples are included in categories above and I believe they are important to the plan.

I also always include a Document Revision table on the second page of these documents and update it whenever I make changes (ok, maybe only when I make big changes).

Answer (score -3):

Embarking on a quality management plan is a commendable effort! For a structured document, consider the PDCA (Plan-Do-Check-Act) cycle. Yes, specifics matter; detailing measures like testing components, acceptance criteria, and incorporating customer feedback is crucial. Quality tools like SIPOC, CTQ, and lessons learned enhance your plan's effectiveness. The choice of tools depends on project needs; tailor them to fit. By the way, while researching quality management tools, I stumbled upon Unichrone's blog on 'Core Tools – 5 Tools of Quality Management.' It's a gem—worth checking out for insights and practical applications. Best of luck with your quality management journey!

Comment: Please include any relevant details in your post. As it stands, this doesn't really answer the OP's question or save them the trouble of looking up off-site resources